# How do I fix this error of "Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x116e337d8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x116e34818)."

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to access a nested firebase database specifically the child of Rating under an auto ID, but how do I access it properly? The `JSON` structure looks like this:

```
users
 Q6jYe9gzAePy8x6SJulTYLMQTpN2
   Fname: Mark Jed
   Lname: Venge
   Rating:
     18e85e0a-9b91-4cb1-a743-792212f1925f
       Rating: 3
       User: k8rn16AAXbTLSyvinD92CugMbL53
```

This is the snippet:

```
for child in snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Rating").children{

  let child = child as! DataSnapshot

  for ratings in child.children{

    let valueSnap = ratings as! DataSnapshot
    let dict = valueSnap.value! as! [String:Any]

  }

}
```

The problem is that "dict" has an error of

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x116e337d8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x116e34818).

Comment: try `let dict = valueSnap.value as? Float`

Comment: what is the actual type of valueSnap.value ?

Comment: Please (learn to) read the error message. It's pretty clear. The left side type is the **actual** type (`NSNumber` – Swift `Int` or `Double`), the right side type is the **wrong** type (`NSDictionary` – Swift `[String:Any]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two nested loops over `snapshot.children`, which seems to be one too many.

It looks like you're starting with a snapshot for a user, and then loop over the children of its `Rating` property.

```
for child in snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Rating").children{
```

So inside this loop the `child` snapshot refers to this:

```
Rating: 3
User: k8rn16AAXbTLSyvinD92CugMbL53
```

You then loop over these children again and try to read each of them as a `[String:Any]`. That doesn't work, since each property here is a single value. And since you can't cast `3` to a `[String:Any]` the app crashes.

There are two options:

1. remove the inner loop:

   ```
   for child in snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Rating").children{
     let child = child as! DataSnapshot
     let dict = child.value! as! [String:Any]
   }
   ```
2. don't cast to a `[String:Any]`, but just get the simple value:

   ```
   for child in snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Rating").children{

     let child = child as! DataSnapshot

     for ratings in child.children{
       let valueSnap = ratings as! DataSnapshot
       let value = valueSnap.value! as! Any
     }    
   }
   ```

**Edit**

To avoid 'Any', the following code will get the rating and user values of each child node directly.

```
let ratingsRef = self.ref.child("users").child("the user id")
ratingsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let allRatingsSnap = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Rating")
    for ratingSnap in allRatingsSnap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        let rating = ratingSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Rating").value ?? "no rating"
        let uid = ratingSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "User").value ?? "no user"
        print("user uid: \(uid)  rating: \(rating)")
    }
})
```

and the output

```
user uid: uid_1  rating: 3
user uid: uid_2  rating: 2
```

Comment: *Don't cast to* `Any` either

Comment: @vadian: the two properties shown in the question have different types, so it's not possible with the loop to cast to any specific type. If you feel there's a better way to handle the use-case, please post an answer showing your suggested solution.

Comment: I am kind with @vadian on 'Any' in this situation... Any is so.... generic, lol. I think the bottom line is the OP wants the values of the specific child nodes. I added a slightly more expanded solution to the already excellent and accepted answer to directly access those nodes.

Comment: Thanks for that edit Jay! It's indeed much nicer if you use named nodes, instead of looping over children, once you reach the property-level. Btw: I think the nested loop is not needed in your code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The nested loop... this one? `for ratingSnap in allRatingsSnap.chi...`? If so... check me on this.. we're reading the user node and then the child node *Rating* which, I assume will have a number of child nodes - there's only one shown in the question but I think the gist of it is there will be multiple children; that structure would be Rating/rating_id_0/rating and Rating/rating_id_0/user. That would be followed by Rating/rating_id_1/rating and Rating/rating_id_1/user etc. So we would need to iterate over each rating_id node. I could of course, be totally wrong too! ;-)

Comment: Ah, got it... you changed the listener. In my samples I stuck to the original code assuming that `snapshot` was a single user (since it does `childSnapshot(forPath: "Rating")`). So there the first loop already gets us to a single rating for that user. I didn't realize you load all ratings for all users, in which case the double nested loop is indeed needed. Thanks for explaining!